# Convert Javascript object to JSON just one time in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to convert javascript object to `JSON` with `angular.toJson` just one time.
my code is:

```
$scope.task.tags = [{"id":22,"tag":"printer","created_at":"2016-03-15" }];

$scope.create = function(task) {
   tmp.tags = angular.toJson(task.tags);
   TaskService.create(tmp);
});
```

and in html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="task.tags">
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="create(task)">save</button>
```

but when click on the `button` more than one time, show me `{{task.tags}}` like this:

1st result:

```
[{"id":22,"tag":"printer","created_at":"2016-03-15"}]
```

2nd result:

```
"[{\"id\":22,\"tag\":\"printer\",\"created_at\":\"2016-03-15\"}]"
```

3rd result:

```
[{\\\"id\\\":22,\\\"tag\\\":\\\"printer\\\",\\\"created_at\\\":\\\"2016-03-15 09:59:23\\\"}]\""
```

Comment: Ehsan, You should not do .toJSON, because .task.tags is already json object.

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify()` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Hi num8er, I use php Laravel as back-end. when send raw js object to api, `json_decode` error to parse string. but when I convert with `angular.toJson` my problem solved. I had to convert.

Comment: @num8er is right there. You already have a valid JSON there in tags. However if you want that, use a check like `if (!converted)` in your create function.

Comment: shaohao-lin, I use `JSON.stringify()`, but result same as this

Comment: Ehsan, if Your service is sending data, so You can just send data normally by passing json object, $http service (angular) will convert them to post fields.

Comment: Where is this `tmp` variable declared?

Comment: num8er, I use `Restangular` to send and create record

Comment: Sam Bauwens, I define `tmp` in `create` function

Comment: Actually you don't declare it, you should do `var tmp;`, then `tmp.tags = ...`. Of course that doesn't solve the answer, but it's better to declare a variable before you use it, otherwise it lives in the global scope.

Comment: This seems like an ugly workaround to simply handling the data properly at server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Angular JSON filter` and the `angular.isObject` method:

```
$scope.create = function(task) {
    var taskTagsCopy = angular.copy(task.tags);

    tmp.tags = angular.isObject(taskTagsCopy) ?  $filter('json')(taskTagsCopy) : taskTagsCopy;
    TaskService.create(tmp);
});
```

I've created a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24444/). You can check the console to see that the object is converted once and once only.

**EDIT**

I've added a `angular.copy`so the `task.tags` won't change anymore.

Comment: but result same as above

Comment: why `task.tags` change to `JSON`? I want to json `tmp.tags` but `task.tags` stay in before state

Comment: Are you sure it's changing ? task.tags isn't touched so it shouldn't. I've updated the JSFiddle to demonstrate you that it isn't changed, check it out!

Comment: Yes, I checked like you but unfortunately `task.tags` changed

Comment: @Ehsan Post edited, so is the JSFiddle, try this out :)

Comment: @Erazihel I am getting an error "TypeError: The value of the property '$filter' is null or undefined, not a Function object ". What do I need to do?